# De quoi de pas bon

Tags: expressions, québec

*L'amour, c'est du caca* d'Alexandra Larochelle :

> Je peux pas gérer ça. Il faut que je parte. Je bondis sur mes pieds.
>
> -- Qu'est-ce que tu fais ? me demande-t-il en sursautant.
>
> J'ai pas le temps de réfléchir à une excuse.
>
> Je vais à la toilette. Pour longtemps. J'ai mangé **de quoi de pas bon**
> ce midi. Ça gargouille beaucoup. Au revoir !

Je comprends cette tournure, *de quoi de pas bon*, mais je la trouve un peu étrange. Je l'ai cherchée sur Internet, il n'y a pas beaucoup de résultats, et tous sont des sources québécoises. Donc, c'est une expression familère que l'on n'emploie pas souvent ?

Answer (score 4):

[*Wiktionnaire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pogner_de_quoi) semble le seul à expliquer que "En français québécois populaire, *de quoi* est souvent employé dans le sens de « quelque chose » : « Je vais te dire de quoi. »". Vient-il de « ce qui est nécessaire » (*avoir de [quoi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/quoi)*) ? Je ne sais pas. On peut retrouver ce *de quoi* dans certaines locutions. Le *pas bon* est un adjectif sous forme de litote ou similairement, qui signifie essentiellement *mauvais* (d'*indigeste* en contexte). La préposition *de* permet d'introduire l'attribut du complément d'objet, voire l'épithète, et est obligatoire avec *quelque chose* dans des tours comme *il y a/il est*, sauf exceptions (on lira avec intérêt LBU14 § 244-246) ; mais la phrase en question n'est pas exactement « il y avait quelque chose de mauvais dans ce que j'ai mangé ce midi » mais plutôt :

> J'ai mangé quelque chose qui était mauvais ce midi.

Je ne sais pas si le reste du tour fait partie de la langue commune dans ce contexte... Probablement que oui, puisque ça correspond à *j'ai mangé quelque chose d'indigeste*, qui me semble parfaitement usuel.

Comment: Je ne connais pas l'expression _pogner de quoi_ dans le sens présenté au Wiktionnaire. Je comprends _ça me fait de quoi_, peut-être moins fort.

Comment: Merci ! Je pense que si _de quoi_ est employé dans le sens de _quelque chose_, cette expression devient plus compréhensible (pour moi). Donc, cela veut dire _J'ai mangé quelque chose de pas bon_ = _J'ai mangé quelque chose d'indigeste_. Je ne savais pas auparavant que _de quoi_ pourrait aussi signifier _qqch_. Je ne l'ai jamais entendu ni lu avant.

Comment: @Oreste Oui le _de quoi_ est très courant à l'oral populaire. Mais ne supplanterait possiblement pas un emploi plus usuel comme dans _je vais te dire de quoi après_ en réponse à _de quoi parlez-vous ?_. Aussi, à part les expressions comme _ça me fait de quoi_, pogner etc., on peut sans doute trouver _(t')as-tu de quoi?_, pour moi c'était une manière subtile de solliciter un vendeur de pot hahahah, peut-être que c'est le sens _le nécessaire à_. Si il s'est passé qqc. et qu'une personne te demande ça, ça voudrait dire _es-tu correct_ dans le sens _est-ce que ça va_. Je ne m'étais jamais demandé.

Comment: D'accord, merci. _et qu'une personne te demande ça_ Désolée, je n'ai pas compris. si quelqu'un me demande quoi ?

Comment: Si quelqu'un te demande _(t')as-tu de quoi ?_ dans un contexte d'accident ça pourrait signifier qqch. comme _es-tu blessée/est-ce que ça va?_ @Oreste